# What are the exponentiable morphisms of schemes?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Recall that a morphism $f:X\to Y$ in a category $\mathcal{C}$ with pullbacks is called **exponentiable** if the pullback functor $f^\ast : \mathcal{C}/Y\to\mathcal{C}/X $ has a right adjoint.  If $Y$ is a terminal object, this is equivalent to the existence of exponential objects $[X,-]$.

Niefield's thesis in 1978 showed that a morphism of affine schemes $\operatorname{Spec}(A)\to\operatorname{Spec}(R)$ is exponentiable if and only if $A$ is finitely presented flat as an $R$-module, equivalently finitely generated projective, equivalently dualizable. (for some intuition: Cagliari showed in 1991 that the exponentiable morphisms in the category of compact Hausdorff spaces are the local homeomorphisms, so some kind of étale condition is unsurprising in retrospect)

Does this result globalize?  When is a morphism of schemes or varieties exponentiable?

I had assumed this was a standard result (and I still think it is likely a corollary of a standard result) but the term "exponentiable" may not be popular in algebraic geometry papers so I've been unable to find it, despite an obvious link with the fppf topology.

Comment: It is related to the representability of the $\mathrm{Hom}$ functor on schemes. See Grothendieck's FGA or the more recent book *Grothendieck's FGA explained*.

Comment: I think the right adjoint $f_*\colon\mathsf{Sch}_{/X}\to\mathsf{Sch}_{/Y}$ of the pullback functor is often called in this context either "restriction of scalars" or "[Weil restriction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weil_restriction)". I don't really know many nice references for these, but some include section 4.6 of [Poonen's rational points book](https://math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/Qpoints.pdf), section 7.6 of the [Néron Models book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-51438-8). There's also [this paper by Olsson](https://math.berkeley.edu/~molsson/homstackfinal.pdf).

Comment: (PS This is completely off-topic (I will delete this comment in a bit), but I can't help but mention, given the opportunity/coincidence, that I've been studying hypergroups, hyperrings, etc. lately, and happened to come across your thesis in the past few days, which I found extremely interesting and very illuminating for the theory! I've been really enjoying reading it :))

Comment: @Emily Thanks, I very much appreciate it. (both comments!) This question originated from picking up my thesis work last year, actually, specifically from reading the 2016 paper of Niefield characterizing coexponentiability and projectivity for quantales. Somehow there is a connection here to hypergroups, though I wish I could tell you what it is!

Comment: So it seems like "finite flat morphisms of schemes are exponentiable" can be proven following the references Emily gave and Niefeld's thesis, and the question is whether the converse is true.

Comment: @AndrewDudzik Oh, I hadn't heard about that paper, it also looks super cool; thanks for mentioning it! (And best of luck in figuring out the connection! :)

Comment: @WillSawin I think the statement "finite flat morphisms of schemes are exponentiable" requires some assumptions, *e.g.* everything is quasi-projective. (More generally, there is this notion of $\mathrm{AF}$-ness defined in the reference below.) On the other hand, the analogous statement holds without further assumptions if we work with algebraic spaces.  I got this from [Rydh's *Representability of Hilbert schemes and Hilbert stacks of points*](https://arxiv.org/abs/0802.3807)